# Result to populate from the worksheet to listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

i have a userform as defined..... multipage option is what i have choose to create or generate the report and inside the multipage page name is created . This is all again inside a frame mentioned below.

```
UserForm Name: "REPORTS"
MultiPage Name: "ReportsMultiPage"
Page Name: "AllRecord"
ListBox Name: "RecordDataList"
Frame name = famallreport
OptionButton Names:
"All"
"Dayvist"
"FAM"
"FAMstay"
"Media"
"Mediastay"
"Interline"
"Agentbooking"
```

i have a sheet called sync where i have a lot of columns ( this is becuase a huge data is stored ) from A to AAZ column. Out of these column i want to display the specific columns as displayColumns = Array(1, 2, 19, 20, 7, 6, 8, 699, 17, 12, 41, 30, 31, 45, 66, 67) and give a manual header as headers =

```
Array("CompForm No.", "Status", "Arrival Date", "Arrival Flight", "Stay Type", "Confirmation No.", "Guest Names", "Show Room?", "Travel Agent", "Total Pax", "Total Nights", "Departure Date", "Departure Flight", "Room Type", "Comments", "Other Comments")
```

when the userform is initiate the default optionbutton value is All and it just has to do nothing but to give the result based on the columna nd the header . I also got 7 other optionbuttons which if selected it will then check the worksheet called sync and then filter the same names given to the optionbutton to this sheet in column G and if the value is there then it should say no data else it should show the filtered data to the listbox in the userform .

[image: image of userform]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have not created a code but want the community to help me create code based on the details provided so i can get the answer in the listbox . The useform and the detials and the options button is already in the image shared and based on those i want the result to be displyed in the listbox.

Comment: Private Sub InitializeUserForm()
    Dim reportListBox As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim columnsArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long, x As Long
    Dim syncSheet As Worksheet

    ' Initialize the reportListBox
    On Error Resume Next
    Set reportListBox = REPORTS.famreport.ReportsMultiPage.AllRecord.recorddatalist
    On Error GoTo 0

Comment: ' Check if the ListBox is properly initialized
    If reportListBox Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "ListBox not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Set reference to the "Sync" sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set syncSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sync")
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Check if the sheet is found
    If syncSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sync sheet not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Clear the ListBox before adding new items
    reportListBox.Clear

Comment: ' Hardcoded columns to display
    columnsArray = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P")

    ' Set the ColumnCount property to match the maximum number of columns
    reportListBox.ColumnCount = UBound(columnsArray) - LBound(columnsArray) + 1

    ' Set the ColumnWidths property based on the number of columns
    reportListBox.ColumnWidths = "60,40,53,40,40,30,30,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90"

Comment: ' Loop through rows in "Sync" sheet and populate ListBox
    lastRow = syncSheet.Cells(syncSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data found in the Sync sheet."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' Add a new row to the ListBox
        reportListBox.AddItem

        ' Loop through selected columns
        For x = LBound(columnsArray) To UBound(columnsArray)

Comment: ' Check for errors or empty cells
            If Not IsError(syncSheet.Cells(i, columnsArray(x)).Value) Then
                ' Populate the ListBox with data from the "Sync" sheet
                reportListBox.List(i - 1, x) = syncSheet.Cells(i, columnsArray(x)).Value
            Else
                ' Handle error or set a default value
                reportListBox.List(i - 1, x) = "N/A"
            End If
        Next x
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

Comment: ' Select the first item in the ListBox
    If reportListBox.ListCount > 0 Then
        reportListBox.Selected(0) = True
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code you have in there and delete your comments. This is a mess.